# Is size_t large enough to represent size of any type?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, size-t

Is `size_t` guaranteed to be large enough to represent size of any type? According to [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t) reference:

> `size_t` can store the maximum size of a theoretically possible object
>   of any type (including array).

This is generally a reliable reference but I could not find anything proving or disputing this claim in the relevant parts of the standard.

Comment: size_t is the type "returned" by the sizeof operator so compilers should make sure declared objects fit it. As for dynamically allocated arrays, I don't think there's technically a guarantee, but practically, implementations will often limit allocated sizes even down to ptrdiff_t to prevent UB in distant pointer subtractions in the same object.

Comment: @PSkocik That's why I tagged it with "language-lawyer"

Comment: @PSkocik Given that the size argument to `malloc()` is a `size_t`, it seems rather difficult to imagine an implementation able to dynamically allocate anything larger than `size_t` can represent.  If you assume `calloc()` can allocate a larger object because the resulting size is the product of the multiplication of two `size_t` arguments, that implies that there must be an unsigned integer type capable of representing sizes larger than `size_t` and that larger type should have been used as the actual `size_t` type.  That seems perverse at best.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes

Comment: @PSkocik Well, a bit of digging shows that "[t]he `calloc` function allocates space for an array of `nmemb` objects".  Is an array considered one object per the C standard?  If not, that's a loophole that would allow `calloc()` to create arrays larger than `size_t` could represent.  And now we're well down the language-lawyer theoretical rabbit hole....

Answer (score 0):

Yes. size_t is defined in stddef.h, according to the [C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) in the section on the sizeof operator (6.5.3.4):

> The value of the result is implementation-defined, and its type (an unsigned integer type)
>   is `size_t`, defined in `<stddef.h>` (and other headers).

Since

> The `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand

and its return type is `size_t`, `size_t` must be able to contain the size of any type.

Comment: It doesn't say "It is large enough" anywhere. Specifically, it doesn't say anything about the "maximum size of a any theoretically possible object"

Comment: @Ayxan However, it *does* say that "The `sizeof` operator  yields  the  size  (in  bytes)  of  its  operand". Therefore, `size_t` must be large enough to store the size of any operand to which `sizeof` could be applied (otherwise `sizeof` wouldn't yiled what the standard requires it to yield).

Comment: @Angew There's also undeclared, dynamically allocated objects. It is somewhat conceivable (though practically extremely unlikely) you could calloc more than what fits in size_t, though engaging in such deeply theoretical scenarios is kind of a waste of time, IMO.

Comment: @giusti And that's why my comment says `calloc` not `malloc`.

Comment: @PSkocik How can a system create something known to be larger than `size_t` can hold if some larger type doesn't exist to hold such a size?  Theoretically possible, I suppose, if only because it's somewhere between impossible and harder than I'm gonna put in the effort to do to prove such a system couldn't exist.

Comment: The C standard allows for implementations to have limits and for ideal results of operators to exceed what is representable in a type. While the intent of `size_t` is to be able to represent the sizes of objects supported by an implementation, this is not explicitly stated in the C standard.

Answer (score -1):

Per the C11 standard, [**6.5.3.4 The sizeof and _Alignof operators**, paragraph 2](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.4p2):

> The `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. ...

Thus, `sizeof` can be used to get the size of any object.

Per [paragraph 5](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.4p5):

> The value of the result of both operators is implementation-defined, and its type (an unsigned integer type) is `size_t`, defined in `<stddef.h>` (and other headers).

and `size_t` can hold the result of getting the size of any object.

Ergo, `size_t` can hold the size of any object.

Comment: See @PSkocik comment on the other answer

Comment: @Ayxan And being able to `calloc()` something larger than a `size_t` can represent strongly implies the existence of a type able to represent something larger.  How can you create something of a size known to be bigger than `size_t` unless something exists that can hold a size larger than `size_t`?

Comment: Well, the reference says "a theoretically possible object ", hence the "language-lawyer" tag.

Comment: The C standard allows for implementations to have limits and for ideal results of operators to exceed what is representable in a type. While the intent of `size_t` is to be able to represent the sizes of objects supported by an implementation, this is not explicitly stated in the C standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil No, it's not explicitly stated, but it is explicitly stated that `sizeof()` returns the size of an object - which means **any** object, and that `size_t` must be able to hold that result.  If you can create an object, you can get it's size with `sizeof`, and `size_t` can hold that size.  How does that **not** follow?

Comment: @AndrewHenle: The standard also says the result of `*` (not “returns”; `sizeof` is an operator, not a function) is the product of its operands, but is clearly false for many operands, such as `INT_MAX*INT_MAX` or `UINT_MAX*UINT_MAX`. In 5.2.4, the standard recognizes there are limits where implementations may break down.

Comment: @AndrewHenle `sizeof` *cannot* take the size of the memory region that `calloc` allocates though, for two reasons. 1) Since `calloc` returns a `void *`, `sizeof` on that just returns the size of the pointer type itself, and casting and de-referencing that pointer just returns the size of that type. So as a practical matter, `sizeof` is defined in a way that can never access the size of dynamically allocated memory regions. 2) `calloc` is uniquely defined as returning memory for **multiple "objects"**, not **one** "object", so I'm not sure that the allocated region even counts as "any object".

Comment: @AndrewHenle I see from one of your other comments that you are already aware of the 2nd of my points, but to be clear, even if you think that one is just an unintentional wording loophole, my 1st point one stands alone. However, on further thought I am +1-ing this answer, because I think it is correct for the question as asked. (The question asked about **object of any type**, not "any contiguous memory region that the C standard might allow you to allocate", and while *arrays* are single objects with type, `calloc`-allocated memory is also arguably not "of any type".)

Comment: @mtraceur Thank you for plainly stating what I was doing such a poor job of.  To me it's patently obvious - `sizeof` returns the size of any object, and `sizeof` returns `size_t`.  Ergo to me it follows that `size_t` must be able to hold the size of any one object.